# embedding laravel route in js file

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I have a js file where I `append`/`remove` a navbar-item in the navbar depending upon the size of the screen. One of the problems I have run into is when I use this `href="{{URL::to('/product1')}}"` this works fine and the console it displays as `href="http://localhost/devFairtex/public/product1"`. But when I do the same thing in javascript file like so

```
 var aboutUsLink = "{{URL::to('/aboutUs')}}";
 $('.navbar-nav').append('<li id="aboutUsRemoveList" class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href='+aboutUsLink+'><span>About Us</span></a> </li>');
```

in the console it display as the actual text it does not change to the actual link it displays as `href="{{URL::to('/aboutUs')}}"`

I don't understand the problem. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Is JavaScript code in external file or inside .blade.php file?

Comment: it's a external file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access the JS file is from the public directory, it does not get parsed by the **blade templating engine** thus leaves your blade code `{{}}` as it is.
An approach to solve this is 
in your view (blade file) write this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.aboutUsLink = "{{URL::to('/aboutUs')}}";
</script>
```

and in your javascript file add the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navbar-nav').append('<li id="aboutUsRemoveList" class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href='+window.aboutUsLink+'><span>About Us</span></a> </li>');
});
```

Comment: where  exactly I should put that code. After putting it inside a script tag it now says undefined.

Comment: in your blade template put the code `window.aboutUsLink = "{{URL::to('/aboutUs')}}";` with script tags and in  your javascript file you can put the `$(document).ready()` code .. let me update the answer for you